# Exporting from Unity to Flash Player 11

Tags: flash, unity-game-engine, flash-player-11

Do any of you have experience on this topic?, I'd need to export some 3D app from Unity to FP11, to make a better integration in a flash site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, download Unity3d 3.5 preview and basically just publish to SWF. It works with simple projects. Big projects will have to be optimized a bit.

Make sure to read [FAQ](http://unity3d.com/unity/preview/faq) on the site. There are many limitations. You can't use dynamic loading, asset bundles, videos, complex shaders. Many .NET libraries don't work (System.XML is one of them).

In the latest build they fixed A LOT. So they are moving in the right direction with exporting to flash. But right now it's too early to use it in production.